# Cross region S3 access from AWS EMR Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, emr

My EMR is at us-west-1 but my S3 bucket is at us-east-1 and i'm getting below error.

I have tried  `s3://{bucketname}.s3.amazon.com` but that would create a new bucket with `s3.amazon.com`.

How can access s3 bucket cross region?

```
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Moved Permanently (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: FB1139D9BD8F409B), S3 Extended Request ID: pWK3X9BBRp8BLlXEHOx008RCdlZC64YFTounDYGtnwsAneR0IDP1Z/gmDudRoqWhDArfYLNRxk4=
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1389)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:902)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:607)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:376)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:338)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:287)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3826)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1015)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:991)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1428)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.exists(EmrFileSystem.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:487)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.text(DataFrameWriter.scala:520)
```

Comment: This used to be supported, but somehow changed recently in EMR. It seems to no longer allow access to an S3 bucket in a different region. It also seems to have affected historical AMIs, so it's a change in EMR itself rather than being related to emr-5.0.

Comment: Yeah we were doing cross region s3 access with EMR 4.6 and spark 2.0 upgrade with EMR 5.0 is having this issue.  I was hoping there is an explicit way for me to set different region some how via using `class InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` or something...

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this is problematic. I didn't face such issues "yet" but what do we do in such cases ? Please don't tell me that we have to copy data from one region to another with the S3 API so we can access it. And what's more absurd is historical AMIs being affected by it. It's a huge regression.

Comment: I'm having same issue in hadoop when I moved to EMR 5.0.0 and 4.7.0.  I was using ami-version at 3.2.1 before with no s3 region issues.   My guess is the underlying s3 native file system used for hdfs is choosing to distribute hadoop job info across s3 regions without respecting what S3 regions are setup via the environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is working for me on emr-5.0.0/emr-5.0.3:

Add the following property to the [core-site configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html)

```
"fs.s3n.endpoint":"s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: Finally had some time to test this.  And it seems to be working for s3n, s3a, and s3.  It could have been recently released EMR 5.1.0 but release notes does not specify.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-whatsnew.html

Answer (score 1):

Did reached out to AWS support team and TLDR is that they are aware of this problem and they are currently working on it and hope to fix this for next EMR release but I have no eta.

For "s3a", you can use custom [s3 end points within spark](https://gist.github.com/tobilg/e03dbc474ba976b9f235) at runtime but this does not work for "s3" or "s3n".

Also, you can configure EMR to point to another s3 region on creation time but once you configure this way you are stuck with that region.

This EMRFS's regional bind is applied from [EMR 4.7.2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.7.2/emr-whatsnew.html) and onward according to the support team.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @codingtwinky in the comments, EMR 4.6.0 does not have this problem in the emr.hadoop.fs layer.  My hadoop jobs now work in EMR 4.6.0, but do not work in 5.0.0 or 4.7.0.